# Angular JS: variable is not found

Tags: angularjs, tornado

I'm working with Angular JS and I don't know why is not found the variable "title". I've got this message:

```
NameError: name 'title' is not defined
```

**app.js:**

```
var app = angular.module("octopusApp", []);

app.controller("indexCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope){
    var self = this;
    $scope.title = "";

    console.log("Estoy en la home");
    angular.element(document).ready(function(){
        $scope.title = "Home";
    });
}]);

app.controller("adminCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    var self = this;
    $scope.title = "Admin";
}]);
```

**template.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Octopus Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "{{ static_url('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app = "octopusApp">
    {% block content %}
    {% end block %}
</body>
</html>
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "template.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class = "container" ng-controller = "indexCtrl">
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-md-12" style = "border-bottom: 5px solid #FFFFFF"><h1>{{title}}</h1></div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% end block %}
```

The error makes reference to the "title" variable from indexCtrl.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit I:**

I have modified my code like @Adriani6 has suggested, but it doesn't work :((((

**index.html**

```
{% extends "template.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class = "container" style = "margin-top: 20px" ng-controller = "indexCtrl">
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-md-9">
                <h1>{{!{{title}}}}</h1>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-md-3" style = "padding-top: 20px; text-align: right">
                <a href = "/admin">>> Go To Admin</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style = "margin-bottom: 10px; border-bottom: 5px solid #000000"></div>
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-md-9" style = "text-align: left; width: 100%">
                <input class = "form-control" type = "text" id="url" placeholder="url" />
            </div>
            <div class = "col-md-3" style = "text-align: right">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style = "width: 100%">Send URL</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style = "margin-top: 10px; border-bottom: 5px solid #000000"></div>
    </div>
{% end block %}
```

**Edit II:**

I have made another test. I have tested that the controller is loaded correctly, and it's loaded. But I don't know why I can't access to any varible to the controller neither $scope.name_variable nor self.name_varible.

In this code you can see that I write by console a message when the indexController is loaded:

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("octopusApp", []);

app.controller("indexCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope){
    var self = this;

    angular.element(document).ready(function(){
        console.log("I'm at home!!!");
    });
}]);

app.controller("adminCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    var self = this;
    $scope.title = "Admin";
}]);
```

And this is what I get in the web console:

[image]

But If I try to access to any variable from index.html I get the error exposed initially.

I don't know what happend!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is not an AngularJS error but Tornado. Both of them make use of `"{{ }}"`.

Try putting: `{{!{{title}}}}`, the ! mark inside the brackets should force tornado to ignore and prevent evaluating the contents after explanation mark.

AngularJS will not throw undefined errors if variable referenced inside `{{ }}` is not defined inside scope.

Edit:

You're not seeing the title variable because you've set your `ng-controller` as indexCtrl and it's not defined in your edit.

Alternatively - Try setting $scope.title outside document.ready and see if it'll work.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it doesn't work to me. I've got the same error. I have updated my post with your suggestion.